# differentiability of a function in $R^2$

Tags: real-analysis

I have this function:
$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{|x|^{3/2} y \log y}{|x|+y}&y>0\\
0&y\le0.
\end{cases}
$$

I want to prove differentiability in all $R^2$

I have proved continuity in all $R^2$

The function is differentiable in $\{(x,y) \in R^2: y<0\}$ because is null on it.
If I consider $\{(x,y) \in R^2: y>0\}$ can I say partial derivatives exist and are continuous so the function is differentiable on it?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Are you sure that this $f$ is differentiable everywhere? Consider

$$\frac{f(1,0+h)-f(1,0)}{h}$$

as $h\to 0^+.$